# Windows command prompt creating but not redirecting output to file

Tags: perl, cmd, command-line, io, io-redirection

I'm having the opposite problem of so many posts I've seen on here.

I'm running a perl command written by someone else and the output is all being forced to the screen despite using the ">" command.

Windows clearly knows what I'm intending because the file name I give is being created fresh and new every time I execute my command but the contents/size of the log file are empty and 0 bytes long.

My perl executable lives in a different place than my perl routine/.pl file.

I tried running as administrator and not.

This is not something wrong with the program. Some of my coworkers execute it just fine and there is no output to their screens.

The general syntax is:

```
F:\git\repoFolderStructure\bin>
F:\git\repoFolderStructure\bin>perl alog.pl param1 param2 commaSeparatedParam3 2020-12-17,18:32:33 2020-12-17,18:33:33 > mylogfile.log

>>>>>Lots and lots of output I wish was in a file

Also attempted in the directory with my perl.exe and gave the path to my repo folder's bin.
```

Is there something weird about windows that could create/prevent the > operator behavior?

Here's the kicker: I did `ipconfig > out.txt` just fine, though...nothing written to the screen.

Thanks for any tips for what I could do to try and change the behavior!

Comment: Try `2>` to capture STDOUT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be that the output is being sent to STDERR, while you are capturing STDOUT. Append `2>&1` to capture both to the same file.

```
>perl -e"print qq{STDOUT\n}; warn qq{STDERR\n};" >stdout
STDERR

>type stdout
STDOUT

>perl -e"print qq{STDOUT\n}; warn qq{STDERR\n};" 2>stderr
STDOUT

>type stderr
STDERR

>perl -e"print qq{STDOUT\n}; warn qq{STDERR\n};" >stdout 2>stderr

>type stdout
STDOUT

>type stderr
STDERR

>perl -e"print qq{STDOUT\n}; warn qq{STDERR\n};" >both 2>&1

>type both
STDERR
STDOUT
```

Note that `2>&1` must come after you redirect STDOUT if you want to combine both streams.

Comment: That worked!
`perl routine.pl parameters >filename 2>&1` put the output in the file. Thanks so much!